# GraphQL query to search for pages based on template

Tags: jss, graphql

The following `GraphQL` query returns items based on the Page template:

```
  search(keyword: "Dream",
    first: 10, 
    language: "en",
    fieldsEqual: [{name:"_templatename", value:"Page" }]
  ) {
    results {
      items {
        name
        id
        language
        item {
          url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ATM, Page is the only page template in the solution so the query works fine. There is a need to introduce new (numerous) page types like `Product Page`, `FAQ`, `Organization` inheriting `Page` (mainly for the content editor usability to assign proper insert options).

How to extend the query to cover all the pages *inheriting* Page template?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of targeting the `_templatename` field you should target the multi-valued `_templates` field which contains the inheritance tree for an item. Since this will get translated into a Solr query, despite the fact that we're using the "fieldsEqual" argument the field only needs to *contain* the value, which is perfect for our inheritance filtering use case.

Here's what the changed argument should look like (**be sure to change the ID)**:

```
   fieldsEqual: [{name:"_templates", value:"e6fd0c645a27449caafece6f377b3e3e" }]
```

You'll notice that the value needs to be template *ID* we're looking for, not the name of it. You also need to make sure the ID is normalized to what gets indexed (no brackets, lower case alpha, and no dashes).

If you need to dynamically convert your templates to useable ID's at query time, you may find this method useful: `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.IdHelper.NormalizeGuid`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no OR in the search, you can do a search for each page type, or first do a facetOn: `_templatename` than you know how many items there are for each templateName

But to keep it simple add a CheckBox Field with for example name `IncludeInSearch` default value `1`  to all Page template that can include in the search. and use

`fieldsEqual:[{name:"IncludeInSearch", value:"1" } ]`

and re-index your index.

As a side effect editor have no the option to hide also pages from the search.

Comment: I think it's inaccurate to say there's no "OR" in search. There not might be a boolean OR  on the entire field/value collection, but that's not what's being asked. It's enough that solr (or azure, or other document datastores) will treat "equals" as "does this field have this value in any of its _values_" 

Targeting the `IncludeInSearch` field does not answer the question on filtering items based on template inheritance and can be leveraged regardless of the Page template being used.